# google web app add to home screen

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, web-applications

I have a java script web application and i am using the latest chrome for mobile beta version for my web app.
I am adding the app shortcut to my home screen as specified at google developer page, but the launcher icon I see on my mobile home screen (galaxy i9300, android 4.1) is the icon I want but inside a white page.
Here is my code in my html:

```
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196X196" href="/Files/Images/196icon.png">
</head>
```

I have tried different icon sizes but still no luck.
what am i missing?

Thanks to all,
Shimi

Answer (score 0):

I've used a different value for the "rel" value. Android usually supports the "apple-touch-icon" tag

```
 <link href="/Files/Images/196icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
```

Here's a good link for [reference](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2013/adding-an-icon-for-iphone-ipad-android-to-your-website/)

Answer (score 0):

It is best to follow the guidance here: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen

Note we only actually show the full icon when you set your app to use the `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` tag in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Using these tags will help you. They worked for me  :-)

```
 <link rel=apple-touch-icon  href="../192x192.png">`
 <meta name=msapplication-TileImage content="../144x144.png">
 <meta property=og:image content="../192x192.png">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../192x192.png" sizes="192x192"> 
 <link rel="manifest" href="../manifest.json">
```